# java.io.FileNotFoundException: while trying to send POST request in Android

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am trying to access the information for a particular URL on the localnetwork using this code

```
protected void Authenticate(String mUsername, String mPassword)
{           
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStreamWriter request = null;

    URL url = null;   
    String response = null;         
    String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   

    try
    {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.2.5:8000/mobile/");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();            
        String line = "";
        System.out.println("this is connection "+connection);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
        response = sb.toString();
        // You can perform UI operations here
        System.out.println("this response"+response);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();             
        isr.close();
        reader.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Error
    }
}
```

I can open the url manually in browser of android phone, but when I am trying to deploy it using post request of app, it is showing `java.io.FileNotFoundException:     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)` Please refer log also

```
03-01 16:26:16.976: W/System.err(662): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.2.5:8000/mobile/
03-01 16:26:16.976: W/System.err(662):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
03-01 16:26:16.976: W/System.err(662):  at com.demo.android.LaunchActivity.Authenticate(LaunchActivity.java:111)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at com.demo.android.LaunchActivity.onClick(LaunchActivity.java:76)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
03-01 16:26:16.984: W/System.err(662):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 16:26:16.984: I/System.out(662): login button has been pressed
```

Comment: check if this IP is accessbile from your mobile

Comment: Yeah from mobile browser it is accessible

Comment: Can you check what error you are receiving using [getErrorStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29) method.

Comment: `url = new URL("http://192.168.2.5:8000/mobile/");
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setDoOutput(true);
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    
   System.out.println("this is connection "+connection);
   InputStream errorstream = connection.getErrorStream();
   System.out.println("GetErrorStream  "+errorstream);`

Here errorStream is null

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added permissions in the manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```